# Which Ubuntu version is suitatable for Gazebo and Ros Hydro Simulator?

Tags: 12.04, server, system-installation

I am working on server with 64 bit,8Gb RAM,500Gb HD and nVidia TESLA C2050. I have to use **Gazebo** and **Ros Hydro** Simulator for simulating purpose. If anyone has work experience and idea in this field.Plz Let me know. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The best think of ubuntu for ros hydro its 12.04 LTS. You can see the in the followed link the instructions  for instalation http://wiki.ros.org/es/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu.  Here are examples to start with gazebo "rrbot".http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf

If you will use Camera Stereo in gazebo Nvidia video  graphics, be necesary for it.

Right now im working with Ros Indigo. in ubuntu 14.04 LTS trusty 64 bit

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Link-only answers are not of good quality. Please consider expanding your answer.